# adding contacts to my gmail account using google contacts api through my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, google-contacts-api

I want to use google contacts api to add contacts into my gmail account throgh my rails app. Is it possible to do so??

Answer (score 1):

Yes, see the gdata gem: http://rubygems.org/gems/gdata